# why small perturbations of $x$ produce small perturbations of $h(x)?$

Tags: algebraic-topology

From Allen Hatcher Book

Theorem $1.9$. Every continuous map $h : D^2\to D^2$
has a fixed point, that is, a point $x \in  D^2$ with $h(x) = x $.

[image]

In the theorem of the proof Hatcher say that
Continuity of $r$ is clear since small perturbations of $x$ produce small perturbations of $h(x)$

My thinking :  If small perturbations of $x$ produce small perturbations of $h(x)$  then $r(x)$ will  moved outside of a  circle  and will contradict  $r(x)=x$

see the  diagram given below
[image]

My confusion :why  small perturbations of $x$ produce small perturbations of $h(x)?$

Comment: Because of continuity of $h$?

Comment: You didn't tell us what $r(x)$ is.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $r(x)$ is the intersection of the boundary of the disk and a ray with origin in $h(x)$ and direction $x - h(x)$.

Comment: @PaulSnopov: this is contradictory with "$r(x)$ will moved outside of a circle".

Comment: @YvesDaoust as far as I remember, the usual proof of Brouwer fixed-point theorem consists of constructing such intersection. Here the topic-starter doesn't really give the definition of $r$, but usually this is just an intersection of ray and boundary.

Comment: @PaulSnopov: the OP needs to realize that his question is incomplete or that what he says is incoherent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust im sorry for that mistake  actually Allen hatcher didn't mention $r(x) = \frac{x - h(x)}{\lVert x - h(x) \rVert}$ so  i was  very  confused  .Now I understand it! from HallaSurvivor answer

Comment: @jasmine: thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't believe Hatcher, you can always build the map yourself and check that it's continuous.

If we're given a fixed point free continuous map $h : D \to D$, build the map

$$r(x) = \frac{x - h(x)}{\lVert x - h(x) \rVert}$$

Notice $x - h(x)$ points from $h(x)$ to $x$, and dividing by the norm places us on the unit circle (the boundary of $D$).

Notice, importantly, that we never divide by $0$, since we are assuming $h(x) \neq x$ for each $x$.

Is it more obvious now that this map is continuous?

---

I hope this helps ^_^